# Javascript array stop spaces being selected

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

Hi I have a comment system with emoji and it works excemt it works too well. If you post a link like this `https://www.somelinke.com` it will select the `:/` after the https and change it to an emoji. How can I only change characters that have spaces beside them to emoji symbols?

This is how I have it set up as an array:

```
 b : new Array("angel","colonthree","confused","cry","devil","frown","gasp","glasses","grin","grumpy","heart","kiki","kiss","pacman","smile","squint","sunglasses","tongue","unsure","upset","wink"),           // Emotions Type
            s : new Array(" o:) ", ":3 "," o.O ",":'(","3:)",":(",":O","8)",":D",">:(","<3","^_^",":*",":v",":)","-_-","8|",":p",":/",">:O",";)"),
```

I am guessing  would have to put some sort of symbol on each side of the new array?

Comment: You should consider something else other than spaces, unless you want a lot of random user input to be converted to emoticons. For instance: "That grumpy cat is awesome!" would turn into "That [emoticon] cat is awesome!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your definition array, locate the `":/"` element and then change it to `" :/ "` both leading and trailing space.

Comment: as you can see up there i have tried that for the first 3 but it did not work?

Comment: there must be a trim function in your script. you need to remove the trim